# Laravel can't render view with form and token

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to render the view with the form reset password and laravel can't do it. Don't have errors but view is **all white**. If i change the view to other with a simple `h1` laravel render it.

So, I guess the problem is with the token.

The route is this:

```
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}','Auth\AdminResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('admin.password.reset');
```

The controller function this:

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.reset-admin')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }
```

And the view file is at

```
/resources/views/auth/passwords/reset-admin.blade.php
```

Thanks a lot.

At the end of the render process execute this function:

```
public function handleShutdown()
    {
        if (! is_null($error = error_get_last()) && $this->isFatal($error['type'])) {
            $this->handleException($this->fatalExceptionFromError($error, 0));
        }
    }
```

Blade content:

```
@extends('backend.public.includes.head')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">ADMIN Reset Password</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.password.request') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Reset Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Extrainfo: 
**Take the scripts,** but not render the form.

Error on error.loc

```
2017/07/14 11:19:35 [error] 5048#5048: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/home/vagrant/Code/name/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/Code/name/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/Code/name/public/index.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. require() /home/vagrant/Code/name/public/index.php:22
```

If i put something like alskdaslkd on the view, it render it.

**SOLVED**

The problem is i use extend to head (where i have all the scripts) but in /layouts/default is where i define my "structure" with @yield('content') so if i put @extends('backend.public.layouts.default') on the top of the blade, i can use @section('content')

Comment: Everything looks correct. Do you have some content on **reset-admin.blade.php** ?

Comment: So what is the contents of `auth.passwords.reset-admin`?

Comment: You'd better check the error log in your server logs to see the error message.

Comment: Yes.. @Amarnasan where i can check it?:l

Comment: That depends on your server and environment. If you are using LAMP, maybe in \var\logs\httpd

Comment: Added the error. In bootstrap/autoload.php i have require__dir__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; in the vendor i have: require_once __dir__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

Comment: Solved! I edit the question

Comment: do a composer install, and composer dump-autoload it looks like its having an issue with the autoloader not the view itself